# Linearised Equation from Lubrication Theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I am reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1634v1.pdf) and am unclear as to how equation $(3.9)$ is obtained.  One is supposed to go from

$H''' = \frac{1-H}{H^3}$

to

$\epsilon = A e^{-\zeta} + B \cos(\sqrt{3} \zeta /2 + \phi) e^{\zeta/2}$

(I assume $\epsilon$ is meant to be $H$ here).  $\zeta$ is the position coordinate, so corresponds to $x$.  This is done by assuming that $H''' \cong 0$ and hence that $H = 1 + \epsilon$, then the equation is linearised and solved.  By linearised, is it meant substitute in $1+ \epsilon$, and then throw away all the terms which are higher order in $\epsilon$?  How does one end up with $H$ if $H$ has been changed for $1 + \epsilon$.

If there is some reference in lubrication theory where this is explained, that might be helpful as well.

Comment: With $H = 1+\epsilon$ then $\epsilon ''' = \frac{-\epsilon}{(1+\epsilon)^3}$ and  $\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^3} = 1 - 3\epsilon+...$ so that linearizing, $\epsilon ^{'''} =-\epsilon$ approximately. This has characteristic equation $p^3+1=0$ giving one real root (-1) leading to your exponential term and two complex roots leading to the second term.

Comment: Given that one can find the values of the constants in this expression for $\epsilon$ using the asymptotic boundary conditions, how does one then combine this with the original equation for $H$ and integrate it numerically to find $H''$ onwards from some value of $\zeta$?

Comment: Ah no, I think I see, say you want $H''$ asymptotic value, you already have the equation for $H'''$ so you substitute in $1+ \epsilon$ using the expression you have found for $\epsilon$ with the boundary conditions, then use some software to numerically integrate that expression from $20$, say, to $\infty$ to get some approximate value.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You have $H=1+\epsilon$ so once you know $\epsilon$ asymptotically you know about $H$. Solving for $H$ numerically is completely separate.

Comment: It says in the article 'use equation $(3.9)$ (the equation for $\epsilon$) to numerically integrate the equation for $H'''$ and obtain the asymptotic behaviour of $H''$ as position coordinate tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: So I've used the asymptotic boundary conditions to obtain $\epsilon = e^{- \zeta}$, how is that combined with the equation for $H'''$ in a numerical integration to get the asymptotic behaviour of $H''$ (at least in theory)?

Comment: I think what they're doing is using the $\epsilon$ solution for the main part of the droplet, then solving the original equation (3.8) on each side of the droplet (at the edge the curvature is larger so they include $H'''$). They are using the $\epsilon$ solution to set a boundary condition for the $H$ solutions. It's not super well explained.

Comment: I think it's something like that, I emailed the author and they said ''Equation (3.9) cannot be solved analytically, so we need to integrate it in order to find the unknown constant. We do so from $\zeta>>1$ towards $\zeta << -1$. We thus use the analytical expression $(3.10)$ to express the 3 boundary conditions $H$, $H’$, $H’’$ at a sufficiently large abscissa, from which we start the integration. We use a shooting method, i.e. repeat the numerical integration with different values of the parameter $\phi$ in $(3.10)$ until we obtain $H’’’(-infty)->0$:

Comment: this is the physically sound solution which gives us the value of the unknown constant we were seeking for.''